# Select change not running

Tags: jquery, cordova

I'm building a new app in Cordova. I'm struggling with this "strange" problem.

I've a select which is loaded good in the HTML

Only, when running it, the change function is not working.

Here the code:

```
function loadlocations() {

        $.ajax({
            type       : "POST",
            url        : "https://app.q-r-s.eu/client/get_locations.php",
    crossDomain: true,
            tryCount   : 0,
            retryLimit : 3,
            success    : function(data) {
                var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                // div leegmaken voor we each kunnen doen
                $("#keuzelocatie").empty();
                console.log("locatiesladen"); 
                // eerst kijken of JSON leeg is (let op het ! )
                if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {
                            var select = '<h3><label for="location">Kies uw locatie:</label></h3>'
                                +'<select name="location" id="location" class="form-control" required>'
                                +'<option value="" disabled selected>Maak uw keuze</option>';
                    $.each(result, function(cat, inhoud) {
                            select += '<option data-cat="'+ cat +'" data-vest="'+ inhoud.id +'">'+ inhoud.name +' ('+ inhoud.city +')</option>';
                    });
                            select += '</select>';
                            $("#keuzelocatie").append(select);
                } else {
                    $("#keuzelocatie").append('Geen locaties met QRS gevonden');
                }

            },
            error      : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
                    this.tryCount++;
                    if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
                        //try again
                        $.ajax(this);
                        return;
                    }            
                    return;
                }              
            }
        });
    }    

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#actionbusy").hide();
        loadlocations();
        $("#table").hide();

        $("#location").change(function()
        {
            console.log("locationchange");
        });


    });
```

Even de console.log isn't appearing.

I'm looking for it for days but couldn't find the problem.
This is for a cordova app.

Comment: try replacing `$("#location").change(function()` with `$(document).on('change', '#location', function()` and make sure there is only ONE element with that ID.

Comment: The event you attach is trying to attach when the page is ready, which might not be the same time as your ajax call which builds the select.

Comment: @Dementic, thanks! this worked out. Can you explain to my why this is working and mine not? Because i'm running the same at a normal website and it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to attach an event to an element that does not exist.
You could do it as `$(document).on('change', '#location', function()` instead of `$("#location").change(function()` Which will attach the event also to newly created elements,
Or, create the element and then attach an event, like this:

```js
function loadlocations() {

        $.ajax({
            type       : "POST",
            url        : "https://app.q-r-s.eu/client/get_locations.php",
    crossDomain: true,
            tryCount   : 0,
            retryLimit : 3,
            success    : function(data) {
                var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                // div leegmaken voor we each kunnen doen
                $("#keuzelocatie").empty();
                console.log("locatiesladen"); 
                // eerst kijken of JSON leeg is (let op het ! )
                if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {
                            var select = '<h3><label for="location">Kies uw locatie:</label></h3>'
                                +'<select name="location" id="location" class="form-control" required>'
                                +'<option value="" disabled selected>Maak uw keuze</option>';
                    $.each(result, function(cat, inhoud) {
                            select += '<option data-cat="'+ cat +'" data-vest="'+ inhoud.id +'">'+ inhoud.name +' ('+ inhoud.city +')</option>';
                    });
                            select += '</select>';
                            $("#keuzelocatie").append(select);
                            $("#location").change(function()
                            {
                                console.log("locationchange");
                            });

                } else {
                    $("#keuzelocatie").append('Geen locaties met QRS gevonden');
                }

            },
            error      : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
                    this.tryCount++;
                    if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
                        //try again
                        $.ajax(this);
                        return;
                    }            
                    return;
                }              
            }
        });
    }    

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#actionbusy").hide();
        loadlocations();
        $("#table").hide();
    });
```